# How I can use GATE API in python application?

Tags: python, gate

I made corpus pipeline application in GATE(General Architectural for Text Engineering) for annotating files, can I use the corpus pipeline Application out of GATE as API in python?

Comment: Sorry, I posted this as an answer when I meant to post it as a comment:  

It will help your chances of getting help if you provide more information. Readers here may not know what GATE is or what it means for an application to be "in GATE" or "out of GATE." What do you mean by "use this Application...as API"?

Comment: There is a [GATE plugin for Python](http://gatenlp.github.io/gateplugin-Python/).  Does that help?